# Blender Automatic LoD (Level of Detail) Optimization Disable

Tags: 3d-view, optimization, settings

i was working in a pretty small scene in blender (300mb) and had to open another program to get some files. That program uses a lot of recources but it worked no problem. But when i returned to blender i found my mesh to look werid. As seem in the first picture it seems to simlefy the mesh very agresevly but when i get close as seen in the second picture it goes back to normal.

So how would i turn it off? If i open another blender file it works and looks normal. My quick term solution has been to append all the colections to another blender file but i hope theres a better one for the next time this happens, or if anyone else had or has the same problem.

I have tried looking of LoD setting as this seems to be a similar effect but they don't exist i have also looked at other setting and they all seem fine. I am not running any addons that would do this.

thank you for any help at all.

Blender version 3.5.0

[image]
[image]